# How to solve the following multivariate recurrence relation?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, recurrence-relations

I would like to solve the following recurrence relation:

\begin{equation}
d[n,k] = d[n-1,k] + d[n-1,k-1] + d[n-1,k-2]\ ,
\end{equation}

with the boundary conditions

\begin{cases}
d[0,0] = 1\\
d[n,n] = d[n-1,n-2] & {\it if} & n > 0\\
d[n,m] = 0 & {\it if} & n< 0\ ||\ m<0\ ||\ m>n \ .
\end{cases}

Comment: This is [A071947](https://oeis.org/A071947).

Comment: Thanks @EricTowers